Best way to keep your mySQL info out of a public repo
I am working on a website and using git. The repo is public but I don't want the mySQL info to be part of it. Should I just put the connection code in a file then block that file with .gitignore?
Is there a better, more sophisticated best practice or is it that simple?
I wish git handled mySQL better by default. I can easily save the files but not the database, but as the app grows those files will be dependent on the database. Short of using flat files or some complex mySQL dumping, I haven't found a good solution. I think you can use a db engine that uses files instead of databases, but I've use mySQL for so long I hate changing everything just to accommodate git. Is there a way have git do I mySQL dump/import whenever a push / deploy is performed?
Sorry for the 3 questions in 1 but I didn't want to make 3 threads, especially when I think I know the answer to question 1. This is my first real project in years and I almost feel like I'm having to relearn programming. So much stuff is new - flex box and flex grid and php8.2 in stead of 5 and msqli - everything is better, either a lot or just slightly, but it's so much different stuff all at once. I hope my 38 year old brain can still get it. I'm not able to do the 12 hour coffee flued marathons like when I was in my 20s, I hope programming isn't just a young man's game but I'm trying to work smarter, getting up something and marketing it instead of just cranking out tons of needless code.

Mysql does save data into files, but those are binary and no version control system is really great with binary files. See the answers to multiple duplicate questions on guidance to track database version changes.

Create .env file in your project root. in php use $_ENV or getenv(). add .env file to .gitignore to prevent from being included in Git.
use package vlucas/phpdotenv for PHP for others check equivalent.
Save your credentials in .env as below:
DB_HOST=your_host
DB_USER=your_user
DB_PASS=your_password
DB_NAME=your_database


I actually thought about using environment variables, but the way you said to do it makes sense.

The only thing that doesn't work with this is that my server would display the *.env as plain text. I probably could hae tweaked that, but I just ussed the PHP extension instead.

Regarding the database connection parameters, professional solutions usually use environment variables, as shown in Mohammed's answer. You can store these in an .env file and ignore it with .gitignore.

I wish git handled mySQL better by default. I can easily save the files but not the database, but as the app grows those files will be dependent on the database.

I don't quite get the point of your second question. Do you want to store the structural information of the MySQL database in the repository, so when checking out your repository, you could import it and getting started quickly?
In that case, you can dump the CREATE DATABASE and CREATE TABLE commands into an .sql file. Some MySQL frontends can do it for you. Alternatively, you could have a look at Flyway, a modern database versioning and migration tool -- a little bit like git for databases. It requires some learning (you're never too old), but makes your life easier when you mastered it.

Yeah I wish git could just be given your mySQL info and whatever you did I push it would dump the database and whenever you deployed it would install the new database. Ideally once the database is done it won't change that much, but especially in the beginning the code is kind of worthless without the matching mySQL

As I said, have a look at Flyway. It's probably exactly what you need. If that's too complicated, just export your table structure into a .sql file and store that into your Git repository.
